# How complex is an energy balance for this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, convection

Let's say I have an enclosed room in the shape of a box with forced airflow on the outer walls at an ambient temperature. Each end of the room (forward and rear) has a vent that ducts in warm air to heat the room. I understand that I can perform an energy balance on the system to determine the temperature of the heated room, but now I want to put some sort of "curtain" at some pont in the room to "isolate" the two sections. This would not completely thermally isolate the two sections as their would be heat leakage from one section to the other because of the nonperfect sealing of the curtain, and because of the heat flow through conduction through the "curtain" itself.

Would it be possible to perform an energy balance on the new room configuration to determine the resulting temperature of the two room sections? if so, how complex is the new energy balance.

Comment: Where is the heat going? Leaky walls? Or do you merely care about transfer trough the curtain to have one colder and one warmer section? If you don't care about gradients, it's rather simple.

Comment: What do you mean by "how complex"?